# Рекурсивные запросы в Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

У меня есть подобная такой таблица (в реальной записей гораздо больше):

```
| Host id | Parent_id | Name |
|---------|-----------|------|
|    1    |  (null)   |  A   |
|    2    |  (null)   |  B   |
|    3    |  (null)   |  C   |
|    4    |     1     |  D   |
|    5    |     4     |  E   |
|    6    |     2     |  F   |
```

Из нее хочется получить примерно такой результат:

```
| Host id | Name |
|---------|------|
|    1    |  A   |
|    2    |  B   |
|    3    |  C   |
|    4    |  AD  |
|    5    |  ADE |
|    6    |  BF  |
```

Каким запросом можно получить такой результат?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка в исходных данных. Чтобы в последней строке было `BF`, вам надо исправить `parent_id` в последней строке с `5` на `2`. А так вот:

```
with t as ( select 1 host_id, null parent_id,  'A' name from dual union all
            select 2 host_id, null parent_id,  'B' name from dual union all
            select 3 host_id, null parent_id,  'C' name from dual union all
            select 4 host_id, 1 parent_id,  'D' name from dual union all
            select 5 host_id, 4 parent_id,  'E' name from dual union all
            select 6 host_id, 2 parent_id,  'F' name from dual)
select host_id, replace(sys_connect_by_path(name, ' '), ' ', '') name
  from t
  connect by prior host_id = parent_id
  start with parent_id is null
order by host_id
```

**UPD.**
Еще в догонку.
Можно использовать так называемый "рекурсивный `WITH`", он дает немного контроля над процессом:

```
with t as ( select 1 host_id, null parent_id,  rpad('A', 2000, ' ') name from dual union all
            select 2 host_id, null parent_id,  rpad('B', 2000, ' ') name from dual union all
            select 3 host_id, null parent_id,  rpad('C', 2000, ' ') name from dual union all
            select 4 host_id, 1 parent_id,  rpad('D', 2000, ' ') name from dual union all
            select 5 host_id, 4 parent_id,  rpad('E', 2000, ' ') name from dual union all
            select 6 host_id, 2 parent_id,  rpad('F', 2000, ' ') name from dual),
   rec (host_id, name) as (select host_id, name
             from t
            where parent_id is null
            union all
           select t.host_id, case when length(t.name) + length(rec.name) <= 4000 then rec.name 
                                  else rec.name || t.name end name
             from t join rec on rec.host_id = t.parent_id
              and length(t.name) + length(rec.name) <= 4000
              )
select *
 from rec
```

Здсь оператор `CASE` позволяет не присоединять символы, если результат будет длинее 4000, а условие `and length(t.name) + length(rec.name) <= 4000` позволяет вообще отрезать такие строки. Использовать лучше что-то одно, конечно.

Comment: Спасибо за исправление! Я плохо составил вопрос, реальная таблица содержит гораздо больше данных, мне нужен универсальный запрос.

Comment: Ну так я и написал универсальный. Вместо `from t` пишете `from ...` и название вашей таблицы, а кусок с `with` выкидываете.

Comment: Да, все верно, спасибо! Но у меня получается слишком длинная строка.. 
Error report -
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long

Comment: Значит у вас строка получается больше 4000 символов. Соответственно, надо придумать, что делать с таким результатом. Обрезать или исхитряться как-то. Например, можно в XML завернуть.